# Batch Script to Login into FTP Server and renaming the file in specific format

Tags: batch-file, ftp, rename

Here is my scenario:

I have files on FTP Server which needs to be renamed automatically.  I created a script to rename the file name as follows which is working perfectly on my computer:

```
 @echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=_.-" %%A in ('dir /B TACOS_*') do (
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  call :getmonth %%B
  ren TACOS*_*%%A-%%B-%%C*_*%%D-%%E-%%F_UTC.csv TACOS_%%A!mon!%%C_%%D%%E%%F.csv
  endlocal
)


:getmonth
if "%1" equ "Jan" set mon=01
if "%1" equ "Feb" set mon=02
if "%1" equ "Mar" set mon=03
if "%1" equ "Apr" set mon=04
if "%1" equ "May" set mon=05
if "%1" equ "Jun" set mon=06
if "%1" equ "Jul" set mon=07
if "%1" equ "Aug" set mon=08
if "%1" equ "Sep" set mon=09
if "%1" equ "Oct" set mon=10
if "%1" equ "Nov" set mon=11
if "%1" equ "Dec" set mon=12
goto :eof
endlocal
```

Now I want to run this function on ftp by logging into the server.  For this I am using the following script:

```
FTP -s:ftpscript.txt
```

and the text file is

```
open 192.168.1.5
ftp-user
ftpuser
cd reports/Don
```

The files are basically under Don directory which needs to be renamed using script above.

Questions:

1. Do we need two scripts to handle this ?
2. How can I get the rename done by logging into ftp server

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved with one file only:

```
!cls&echo off&setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
!cls&goto :ftp_border
open 192.168.1.5
ftp-user
ftpuser
cd reports/Don
lcd c:\direcotry_where_the_script_is
mget *.csv
bye

:ftp_border
@echo off
endlocal

ftp -s:%0


setlocal
for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=_.-" %%A in ('dir /B TACOS_*') do (
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  call :getmonth %%B
  ren TACOS*_*%%A-%%B-%%C*_*%%D-%%E-%%F_UTC.csv TACOS_%%A!mon!%%C_%%D%%E%%F.csv
  endlocal
)


:getmonth
if "%1" equ "Jan" set mon=01
if "%1" equ "Feb" set mon=02
if "%1" equ "Mar" set mon=03
if "%1" equ "Apr" set mon=04
if "%1" equ "May" set mon=05
if "%1" equ "Jun" set mon=06
if "%1" equ "Jul" set mon=07
if "%1" equ "Aug" set mon=08
if "%1" equ "Sep" set mon=09
if "%1" equ "Oct" set mon=10
if "%1" equ "Nov" set mon=11
if "%1" equ "Dec" set mon=12
goto :eof
endlocal
```

could you try with this?

Comment: for the directory of the script u mean where i will save this script??

Comment: Thanks for the help...The code u gave doesnt transfer all the files from the FTP server... only 6 files from the Don directory and it doesnt even change the name of the files... furthermore i want the renamed files to be put back on the FTP server in the same don Directory

Comment: if u want i can send u the result of the command prompt if uwant to see that

Comment: can you try the `mget *.csv` after you connect to your storeage with ftp? this should download all files with csv extensions ..

Comment: you can connect to the server with the built in ftp client.Just write `ftp` in command prompt .With `open host` you can connect to the ftp host and with cd and lcd to navigate to local and the remote directoreies.So you can list the files and check if the mget will download them all.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me. This is not an answer to your FTP question, but a discussion on your Batch file; I see some details on it:

In accordance with your FOR command ("delims=_.-") and the name in the REN command, I assume that the format of your files is this:

```
TACOS_YYYY-Mon-DD_HH-MM-SS_UTC.csv
```

Where "Mon" is a three-letter month name, and that you want to rename to this format:

```
TACOS_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.csv
```

If this is true, then your REN command may cause an error because the asterisks imply *several* names! If you want to eliminate characters after TACOS, before YYYY, after DD and before HH, then this is not the way to do it. Perhaps the file names in your computer don't cause problems. Try to create two or more files with the same date and hour and different characters in the other places; in this case, the REN command try to rename two or more files with just one new name (unless you know that there is no way this happen).

Your SETLOCAL/ENDLOCAL pairs are useless. If you want to avoid problems with names that may have exclamation marks, then Delayed Expansion must be disabled when %%A..%%F be expanded. If your names may have exclamation marks, then your program must be modified.

May I propose you another method to convert the three-letter months to two-digits? This method use an *array* with three-letters as subscripts and two-digits as values in the array elements, so the conversion is immediate.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Create the array for months conversion
set m=100
for %%A in (Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec) do (
  set /A m+=1
  set mon[%%A]=!m:~-2!
)
for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=_.-" %%A in ('dir /B TACOS_*') do (
  ren TACOS*_*%%A-%%B-%%C*_*%%D-%%E-%%F_UTC.csv TACOS_%%A!mon[%%B]!%%C_%%D%%E%%F.csv
)
```

If you want to eliminate several characters in the places where you put asterisks in the REN command, then tell us how those characters can be isolated. For example, if one name start with:

```
TACOSxyz_abcYYYY-Mon-DD...
```

then you must realize that %%A in your FOR command is "abcYYYY", not just "YYYY"!

EDIT: There is a possible solution below:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Create the array for months conversion
set m=100
for %%A in (Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec) do (
  set /A m+=1
  set mon[%%A]=!m:~-2!
)
for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=_.-" %%A in ('dir /B TACOS_*') do (
  set YYYY=%%A
  set DD=%%C
  set HH=%%D
  set SS=%%F
  ren TACOS*_*%%A-%%B-%%C*_*%%D-%%E-%%F_UTC.csv TACOS_!YYYY:~-4!!mon[%%B]!!DD:~0,2!_!HH:~-2!%%E!SS:~0,2!.csv
)
```

Comment: The problem i am facing is not with the rename function but to run the rename function in the FTP